# add list indexes to ip address dynamically

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, ip, subprocess

`ip_address = '172.16.%d.%d' % (rack_number, box_number)`

I have got an ip address. The first and second digits are static. 3rd and 4th are going to change based on user inputs.

`rack_number` is an integer. There is no problem there. But, box number is going to be between `1-16`. I am using `list` for that.

Lets say I have got `rack` number `3` and `box_number` `2, 9`

Next I need create two ip addresses to send commands.

So, IP addresses will be `172.16.3.2` and `172.16.3.9`

How can I achieve this in functional way ?

Comment: What do you mean by functional? Anyway, just make `ip_address` a container, probably a list, that is built from `rack_number` and the list `box_number`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *list comprehension* is all you need and the *new style formatting* makes it look better:

```
ip_addresses = ['172.16.{}.{}'.format(rack, box) for box in box_numbers.split(', ')]
```

If `box_numbers` is a list, there'll be no need for *splitting* which only applies to string inputs:

```
ip_addresses = ['172.16.{}.{}'.format(rack, box) for box in box_numbers]
```

Comment: If box_numbers is a list. I don't see the need to split on that. Just a suggestion.

Comment: @SpiderWasp42 *based on user inputs* suggests it is a string

Comment: I think the user inputs are referring to both the rack number and the box_numbers. But I felt that since the OP said clearly that box_numbers can be assumed to be a list, splitting wouldn't be necessary from the perspective of posting an answer. Otherwise, top notch answer. Cheers!

Comment: @SpiderWasp42 Updated ;)